# Using NSUserDefaults to store default values at build time

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am storing a small dictionary of default values which a user can modify later, but probably will only ever be changed once. NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults seems like the right place to store such a thing, my question is: Is there a way to store values at build time instead of runtime? This code seems like it should be unnecessary.

```
if !NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey(default) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(defaultDictionary, forKey: "default")
    }
```

Or, is there a better alternative I should be considering instead?

Comment: Why does it need to be at build time instead of run time? That code seems very necessary to initialize options upon first use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register the default values as described in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html)

> **Registering Your App’s Default Preferences**
>
> At launch time, an app should register default values for any
>   preferences that it expects to be present and valid. When you request
>   the value of a preference that has never been set, the methods of the
>   `NSUserDefaults` class return default values that are appropriate for
>   the data type. For numerical scalar values, this typically means
>   returning 0, but for strings and other objects it means returning `nil`.
>   If these standard default values are not appropriate for your app, you
>   can register your own default values using the `registerDefaults:`
>   method. This method places your custom default values in the
>   `NSRegistrationDomain` domain, which causes them to be returned when a
>   preference is not explicitly set.
>
> When calling the `registerDefaults:` method, you must provide a
>   dictionary of all the default values you need to register. Listing 2-1
>   shows an example where an iOS app registers its default values early
>   in the launch cycle. You can register default values at any time, of
>   course, but should always register them before attempting to retrieve
>   any preference values.
>
> Listing 2-1  Registering default preference values
>
> ```
> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    // Register the preference defaults early.
>     NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"CacheDataAgressively"];
>     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
>  // Other initialization... 
> }
> ```
>
> When registering default values for scalar types, use an `NSNumber` object to specify the value for the
>   number. If you want to register a preference whose value is a URL, use
>   the `archivedDataWithRootObject:` method of `NSKeyedArchiver` to encode
>   the URL in an `NSData` object first. Although you can use a similar
>   technique for other types of objects, you should avoid doing so when a
>   simpler option is available.

Answer (score 0):

To store values at build time, I would make a .plist or a .json file and pre-populate that with the values that you want to store that can then be accessed at runtime.